# How to get the value of input[type=image]?

Tags: jquery

For some reason, I cannot seem to get the value from my inputs. I am using type=image on all of them in my form.

What I would like is to serialize the data and send it to my back end code. Can someone please show me how this should work? I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<form id="test">
  <input type="image" src="test.jpg" alt="test 1" id="test1" name="test1" />
</form>
```

---

```
     var values = $('#test input').serialize();
     var request = $.ajax({
       url: "test.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: values,
       dataType: "json"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

```
$('#test input').val()
```

Your statment would be,

```
var values = $('#test input').map(function(){
                 return $(this).val();
             }).get().join();
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I use serialize then? I would like to serialize the data instead of having to make the query string for 22 inputs?

Comment: Updated my code to get the comma separated values of all input

Comment: Thanks Adil. AllI'm getting back from that is a string of commas. That's weird.

Comment: You do not have value attributs what attribute(s) you want?

Comment: I don't believe you can use the value attribute for a submit. I ran my HTML through a validator and it complained about me having it. Should I use something other than an input?

Comment: Most of time anchor is used for images, what you want to do with this tag?

Comment: Just pass its value back to my back end code. If the user clicks a certain button, there will be a value associated with it. I need that value. I'm not necessarly married to an input tag

Comment: If you want to send value on button click associated with that button then you need to attach event and get value in handler and send it to server or whatever, This may help you, http://jsfiddle.net/jq2Xf/

Answer (score 0):

An input type="image" only defines that image as the submit button and not as an input that can carry  a value to  server